# Converting MS word "curly" quotes and apostrophes

Tags: ms-word, quotes

How do I convert the MS Word quotes and apostrophes to regular quotes and apostrophes characters in Java? What's the unicode number for these characters?

> “how are you doing?”
>
> ‘howdy’

Since Stack Overflow autofixes them, here's how they appear in an editor

[image: Curly Quotes]

to

> "how are you doing?"
>
> 'howdy'

Comment: Not converted here, the ‘smart quotes’ are fine. StackOverflow converts straight quotes to “” in question titles (controversially), but leaves question text alone.

Comment: Incidentally, is there really a good reason to replace them with straight quotes? They're not special “MS Word” characters, they're perfectly valid Unicode characters which should normally by handled fine by any application that can handle Unicode.

Comment: @bobince not all applications handle unicode properly, but often people paste text that they wrote in ms-word and it's nice to be able to preserve the quotes (by converting them to regular quotes) than to strip them out completely.

Answer (score 21):

Going off Thomas's answer, the code is:

```
return text.replaceAll("[\\u2018\\u2019]", "'")
           .replaceAll("[\\u201C\\u201D]", "\"");
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's a very useful link for everyone dealing with Unicode: [Unicode codepoint lookup/search tool](http://unicode.scarfboy.com).

Searching for "quotation mark" gives

```
‘ (U+2018) LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
’ (U+2019) RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
“ (U+201C) LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
” (U+201D) RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
```

There are [several other quote-like symbols](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=quotation+mark) that you might consider replacing.

Comment: The Unicode lookup link given in the answer is a third-party site.  A better, "official" link is at unicode.org:  https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/properties.html

Answer (score 11):

Thank to Nick van Esch at [C# How to replace Microsoft's Smart Quotes with straight quotation marks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334850/c-sharp-how-to-replace-microsofts-smart-quotes-with-straight-quotation-marks)

Here is the code ('\u2019' is ’ in MS Word), it's useful because it covers problematic word characters.

```
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u2013') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u2013', '-');
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u2014') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u2014', '-');
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u2015') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u2015', '-');
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u2017') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u2017', '_');
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u2018') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u2018', '\'');
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u2019') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u2019', '\'');
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u201a') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u201a', ',');
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u201b') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u201b', '\'');
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u201c') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u201c', '\"');
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u201d') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u201d', '\"');
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u201e') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u201e', '\"');
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u2026') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace("\u2026", "...");
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u2032') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u2032', '\'');
if (buffer.IndexOf('\u2033') > -1) buffer = buffer.Replace('\u2033', '\"');
```

Comment: In the above answer, we are mentioning all MS Word quotes. Is there not any simple code which replaces all MS Word Quotes with Straight quotation marks? I mean, how can we list all the MS Word quotes?

Comment: @Anish Mittal: As far as I know, this is the simplest way.