# Parsing huge, badly encoded XML files in Python

Tags: python, xml, encoding, iterparse

I have been working on code that parses external XML-files. Some of these files are huge, up to gigabytes of data. Needless to say, these files need to be parsed as a stream because loading them into memory is much too inefficient and often leads to OutOfMemory troubles.

I have used the libraries miniDOM, ElementTree, cElementTree and I am currently using lxml.
Right now I have a working, pretty memory-efficient script, using `lxml.etree.iterparse`. The problem is that some of the XML files I need to parse contain encoding errors (they advertise as UTF-8, but contain differently encoded characters). When using `lxml.etree.parse` this can be fixed by using the `recover=True` option of a custom parser, but `iterparse` does not accept a custom parser. (see also: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352840/parsing-broken-xml-with-lxml-etree-iterparse))

My current code looks like this:

```
from lxml import etree
events = ("start", "end")
context = etree.iterparse(xmlfile, events=events)
event, root_element = context.next() # <items>
for action, element in context:
    if action == 'end' and element.tag == 'item':
    # <parse>
    root_element.clear()
```

Error when `iterparse` encounters a bad character (in this case, it's a `^Y`):

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0x19 0x73 0x20 0x65, line 949490, column 25
```

I don't even wish to decode this data, I can just drop it. However I don't know any way to skip the element - I tried `context.next` and `continue` in try/except statements.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**

Some additional info:
This is the line where iterparse fails:

`<description><![CDATA:[musea de la photographie fonds mercator. Met meer dan 80.000     foto^Ys en 3 miljoen negatieven is het Muse de la...]]></description>`

According to etree, the error occurs at bytes `0x19 0x73 0x20 0x65`.
According to hexedit, `19 73 20 65` translates to ASCII `.s e`
The `.` in this place should be an apostrophe (foto's).

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325379/hexadecimal-0x19-is-an-invalid-character), which does not provide a solution.

Comment: Did you tried beautiful soup?

Comment: Is it feasible to perform a pre-processing step to correct the encodings? You could probably even do this in a pipeline using a StringIO object and feeding output to etree.

Comment: @DanatheSane It certainly is, any tips on how I could go about this?

Comment: @Rik If you put together some code to parse tag, attr and content parsing, you could feed problematic input into chardet (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file) and re-write the file as you go. I'm not sure where in the document the encoding problems are, but this shouldn't incur too much overhead if they are somewhat isolated.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? And, if 2, can you count on 2.5+, or do you need 2.4 compat? The reason I ask is that codecs.EncodedFile is probably the best solution for 2.5-2.7, but it has some problems in 2.4, and there may be even simpler answers in 3.x.

Comment: Please post a complete XML document that includes your top-level tag and DTD (if any) as well as the fragment, so other people can test the same thing you're testing. Also, if you can show a couple bytes before the error that might help (so we can see whether we've got half a UTF-8 character or something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the problem is being caused by *illegal* XML characters, in this case the 0x19 byte, I decided to strip them off. I found the following regular expression [on this site](http://lethain.com/stripping-illegal-characters-from-xml-in-python/):

```
invalid_xml = re.compile(u'[\x00-\x08\x0B-\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]')
```

And I wrote this piece of code that removes illegal bytes while saving an xml feed:

```
conn = urllib2.urlopen(xmlfeed)
xmlfile = open('output', 'w')

while True:
    data = conn.read(4096)
    if data:
        newdata, count = invalid_xml.subn('', data)
        if count > 0 :
            print 'Removed %s illegal characters from XML feed' % count
        xmlfile.write(newdata)

    else:
        break

xmlfile.close()
```

Answer (score 10):

If the problems are actual character encoding problems, rather than malformed XML, the easiest, and probably most efficient, solution is to deal with it at the file reading point. Like this:

```
import codecs
from lxml import etree
events = ("start", "end")
reader = codecs.EncodedFile(xmlfile, 'utf8', 'utf8', 'replace')
context = etree.iterparse(reader, events=events)
```

This will cause the non-UTF8-readable bytes to be replaced by '?'. There are a few other options; see the documentation for the codecs module for more.

Comment: Hm, this looks like a great solution, but I've just tried it - same error at the same point, even when I change 'replace' to 'ignore'. (To answer your question above, this is Python 2.7, no compat required.)

Comment: Can you post the XML file (or, better, a small document displaying the problem) somewhere, so people can help debug it?

Answer (score 1):

I used a similar piece of code:

```
 illegalxml = re.compile(u'[\x00-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1F\uD800-\uDFFF\uFFFE\uFFFF]')
```

...

```
illegalxml.sub("?",mystring)
```

...

However, this did not work for all possible strings (400+MB string).

For a final solution I used decoding/encoding as follows:

```
outxml = "C:/path_to/xml_output_file.xml"
with open(outxml, "w") as out:
    valid_xmlstring = mystring.encode('latin1','xmlcharrefreplace').decode('utf8','xmlcharrefreplace')
    out.write(valid_xmlstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with char "" in my xml file, which is also invalid xmlchar. This is because in the xml version 1.0, the characters like &#x0, &#xE are not allowed. And the rule is that all character composition as regular expression '&#x[0-1]?[0-9A-E]' are not allowed. My purpose it to correct the invalid char in a huge xml file, based on Rik's answer, I improved it as below :

```
import re

invalid_xml = re.compile(r'&#x[0-1]?[0-9a-eA-E];')

new_file = open('new_file.xml','w') 
with open('old_file.xml') as f:
    for line in f:
        nline, count = invalid_xml.subn('',line)
        new_file.write(nline) 
new_file.close()
```